# Blender 2.79, how to install Khronos Group gltf exporter?

Tags: export, add-on, installation, linux, gltf

1. I downloaded the KhronosGroup addon from https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter
2. I read install instructions, but those were for Windows.
3. I tried copying the addon under ~/.blender/2.79/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2 but Blender shows nothing
4. I tried to install via "install from file" and selecting the exporter .py file directly but nothing happens.
5. I checked version, I am sitting in 2.79 Blender and the script is for 2.78. I tried to fool Blender by changing the scripts version in to 2.79 but no luck.

Any way to get this thing to work on Linux and on this Blender version?

Comment: Copying `io_scene_gltf2` into `scripts/addons` as per the readme worked fine for me in 2.79b under Archlinux. Have you tried refreshing Blender?

Comment: To which exact path did you copy the file into if I may ask? Also, what do you mean by refreshing? Restarted many times if that's it.

Comment: I copied `glTF-Blender-Exporter/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2` to `~/.config/blender/2.79/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2`. Restarting Blender would certainly do it; there's also a refresh button in the bottom right corner of the addon list

Comment: For those that have arrived here in the year 2022 just go to `File > Export > glTF 2.0` in Blender.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you gandalf3. My mistake was the path.
I tried ~/.blender folder when in fact I had to copy the addon under ~/.config/blender/..

Works now, thank you again!